# Retrofit Get method with parsed url

Tags: java, android, url, retrofit2

I am working on the project that includes a call to API.
The API has implemented pagination in response.
I am getting next page's URL inside the response header.
It is some sort of parsed URL like %3A for ':' and %2F for '/'.
so is there any way in the retrofit that I can call get method using that URL.

thank you in advanced

Comment: can you Please attach the code ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this

```
@GET(Endpoint.URL")
Call<ListResponse> getList();
```

Comment: If it doesn't help then can you please add a url!

Comment: @Urvishrana please send me the URL, so I can get better idea

Comment: @Urvishrana, please decode URL first using URLDecoder.decode(stingvalue, "UTF-8"); then you will be able to call get method

Answer (score 0):

**Use this I think it will works**

```
  @GET("api/v1/driver/my_trips/{UNIQUE_ID}")
  Single<BoookingDeails> getCurrentList(@Path("UNIQUE_ID") String id);
```

Comment: No it's not about passing data inside url i want to pass the whole url